# Google Sheets Filter Lines with no Empty Colums - AT LEASTS ONE conlum filled

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I need help with Google Sheets.

Someone, know how to do a filter and sort lines with "no Blank Coluns".

I need filter names(Each Lines) - That has number 1 check AT LEASTS ONE in green colum.

I need list all names in top, that has number 1 in green colum, at least one column filled.

- Names(each Line) with **ALL EMPTY COLUM**, empty green colum, can be displayed after.

It's possíble to do?
Some article to me sutdy? someone to help make this? thanks all

DemoData: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U8CiUjjfllnsGPyg-Sek0CPuyHpJGSwLJ-W2bq_98Ds/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Web Apps Stack Exchange! A spreadsheet with a dummy data would help us immensely here. A screenshot isn't terribly helpful, as we are not able to work out any cell reference. Thank you for your understanding. P.S. there might be a very simple solution with a helper column, though I can't be sure without your sheet.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U8CiUjjfllnsGPyg-Sek0CPuyHpJGSwLJ-W2bq_98Ds/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I Create a Colum Before K.

J Colum, i make formule: =COUNTUNIQUE(L61:AM61)

The logic is sum all coluns filleds. Return 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Now, I can sort the colum J by Desc.
And too, filter the date.

And I get List by date, and sorted by Desc(any colum of K-Z ).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

*It's a pity that you didn't heed **David Tan's** advice and didn't give a link to your table - it's really completely unclear from the screenshot where your data starts on the sheet and how far it extends to the right.*

Let's say you start your spreadsheet in cell **A1** (at least people usually do that). In this case, we see that you have eight **A:H** columns in red, two **I:J** columns in yellow, and at least eight **K:R** columns in green. And you want to use the values of these green columns as the sort criteria.

There are tricky tricks that allow you to process individual rows of a range. However, I do not advise you to look towards `MMULT()`, `SEQUENCE()` and others - formulas using them are difficult to understand, apply and edit. Take it easy - sum the individual columns of the filter range:

```
=SORT(A1:R,K1:K+L1:L+M1:M+N1:N+O1:O+P1:P+Q1:Q+R1:R,0)
or
={A1:R1;FILTER(A2:R,K2:K+L2:L+M2:M+N2:N+O2:O+P2:P+Q2:Q+R2:R)}
```

Yes, this construction seems clumsy and unwieldy, but you only need to enter it once.

Comment: Thanks, i will try. I create demo sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U8CiUjjfllnsGPyg-Sek0CPuyHpJGSwLJ-W2bq_98Ds/edit?usp=sharing